# Get first Google Image Web service

Tags: ios, image, web-services

I'm building an iOS app and I need somewhere to get images from Google image. Let's say I'm looking for "iPhone 5s", i'd like to get the first Google image result for this research.

Is that any way to achieve this ? Maybe by building the "right" URL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I found [This useful link](https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide#basic_query), how ever it is not returning the first image, but i hope it cam be fixed. see if it is useful. Go through **Sending a basic query**, Here they have created a request which response into JSON format from which you can get what you need.
Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: So what I need to do is find a way to integrate this HTML api in my iOS app ? Is It possible ?

Comment: Have found some useful thing for you, please check the updated answer.

Comment: Yeah ! That seems nice and should do the trick. Thank you, this helps me a lot :)

Comment: This has been deprecated, and the Custom Search API should be used instead.